# Best R package for doing Fourier Analysis for three dimensional function

Tags: r

I want to find a function that approximates a function that produces output that looks like:
Blue, Red and Green are the X, Y and Z space dimensions.

[image]

What R package should I use?

Comment: This looks like a curve in 3D... going back to the topic, you need fourier transform, spline, smoother or what?

Comment: Since you have X, Y, and Z all parameterized by time, why can't you use fourier transform on each of them separately to obtain X(t), Y(t), and Z(t) in terms of sines and cosines?

Comment: I think need fourier transform.

If I however fourier transform them separately I would think that I lose information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this question is very old, but has it been resolved yet for you?

First the short answer: You should use

- Library TuneR for the function periodogram()
- Library strucchange for the function Wave() with which you build an object that will plot nicely

Considering your comment about losing information if you apply a fourier-transform on the 3 dimensions separately instead of, say, on the vector for each point in time: You will lose information anyway in the fourier-transform. The best you can do is make sure the axes are orthogonal. Looking at your data, even running the fourier over only one dimension will give you the major frequency without problems.